# Render control in background

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a slow to render control. How can I render it in the background?

At present, its rendering is triggered when it's added to a parent view in the page. But that requires the `Add` running on the UI thread, which thwarts my plan.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why is it slow to render, exactly?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm guessing because it does lots of drawing. It's a calendar.

Comment: On my slow Android, the whole UI freezes for about a second.

Comment: Is it a control you authored? How are you rendering it? Drawing a calendar is presumably just a bunch of lines and numbers - that shouldn't be expensive at all.

Comment: I agree with @Dai because i made a similar control not too long ago and it loaded like a charm

Comment: It’s the Telerik Xamarin.Forms calendar with some custom drawing. I’m going to try Xamarin.Forms 3 and drop the native version in for Android.

Comment: Well, on my very slow Android phone, the native calendar loads in less than two seconds. The Forms version is holy-s**t slow to load. Perhaps my customisations will slow it down some.